# Possible to batch sql queries?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm a novice MySQL user so could really use a little advice here. I've inherited a program that currently processes text files consisting of approximately 100,000 records each. Each line is it's own record and gets processed. A file like this can be completed in about a minute as nothing to intense is being done, mostly just string comparisons.

Anyway, now some SQL queries have to be added to the process without slowing things down too much. Essentially, it's possible that each of those 100,000 lines will now need to make a SQL select statement to query a DB and see if more data is accessible. I threw together a rough start and it takes the processing time from a minute to about an hour. Definitely unacceptable. My question is, is there even way to speed this up? (I'm sure there is)

I'm only opening one connection object but I don't see any way around making that individual SQL query for each record. Is there a way to batch select statements? Any advice would be very helpful, thank you.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I should have been more explicit. This is for SQL select statements. I know how to do batch Inserts, that's no problem. I don't understand if batch select statements are possible or how to speed them up.

Also, someone mentioned Indexes, but I don't know anything about indexes. Could someone provide me some info on them?

Comment: Are you doing a SQL insert or SQL select?

Comment: Without knowing the SQL queries, we can't really help much.  Post a sample of the queries you are running and we might be able to help you streamline it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speed up `SELECT` by creating an [index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) for the columns which commonly appear in the `WHERE` clause.

Speed up batch inserts by wrapping them all in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Comment: just be careful with creating indexes you know why. but clear answer +1.

Comment: i don't know why. I don't know anything about indexes. What are the things to watch out for?

Comment: They can be quite big, and edits to the tables you're SELECTing from  can slow down as the indexes have to be updated.

Comment: I don't think that woudld be an issue as these tables are created once, never edited, and thrown away after a few days. They only exist to be selected from.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a good use for PRE INSERT TRIGGER code. - in other words, let the database do the work when presented with an incoming row.

Comment: i'm asking about select statements, not insert statements. So I don't think this applies.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a select statement, you could use the **in** keyword.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

**SQL IN Syntax**

```sql
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```